# Append number with class name in razor

Tags: razor

I have a div with a class name in razor code.I want to append a number programatically to the class name. my div

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

I need to add count++ value to append to the class name test.Then the result class name should be test1

here is my code

```
 var count=0;
  foreach(var item in items)
    {
    count++;
    <div class="test+@count++"></div>

    }
```

but it showing test+1 can any one help

thanks in advance

Comment: How much evements you have in `items`? Have you try just `<div class="test @count"></div>`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use parentheses to separate the variable name from static text:

```
var count=0;
foreach(var item in items)
{
    count++;
    <div class="test@(count)"></div>
}
```